# How to find point of tangency with center of circle and tangent line equation

Tags: geometry, circles, tangent-line

Find the equation of the circle with center $(3,4)$ that is tangent to the line whose equation is $y = 2x + 3$.

I know you can use the distance between a point and a line formula but according to my math teacher, there's another way to solve it by finding the point of tangency first. Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Yes, there are different methods (not all equally convenient). Have you made an effort to look up something on your own?

Answer (score 2):

Let the equation of the circle be $$(x-3)^2+(y-4)^2=r^2$$

Substituting $y=2x+3$, $$(x-3)^2+(2x+3-4)^2=r^2 \\ (x-3)^2+(2x-1)^2=r^2 \\ x^2-6x+9+4x^2-4x+1=r^2 \\ 5x^2-10x+10-r^2=0$$
If the circle is tangent to the line, the last equation should yield a unique solution for $x$, i.e. the discriminant is $0$:
$$10^2-4\cdot5\cdot(10-r^2)=0 \\ \implies r^2=5$$

Answer (score 1):

The equation of circle will be 
$$(x-3)^2+(y-4)^2=a^2$$, where $a$ is radius of the circle.

Now to find the radius of circle find distance of center (3,4) from tangent, $y=2x+3$ which would be :
$$  | \frac{-5}{\sqrt5}|$$ that is $\sqrt5$

so your equation is:
$$(x-3)^2+(y-4)^2=5$$

Comment: I assumed you know formula for distance of a point from a line.

Comment: The line the circle is tangent to is $y=2x+3$, not $y=x+3$.

Comment: My mistake, I'll correct that, thanks for telling me @GeorgeLaw

Comment: The answer I got was $(x-3)^2+(y-4)^2=5$ – http://www.mathsisfun.com/data/grapher-equation.html?func1=(x-3)%5E2%2B(y-4)%5E2%3D5&func2=y%3D2x%2B3&xmin=-1.606&xmax=8.394&ymin=-0.5422&ymax=6.958

Comment: Thanks @GeorgeLaw I didn't realized that it'd be $|\frac{-5}{\sqrt5}|$ so many silly mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

Let the point of tangency be $(a,b)$. The line joining the centre of the circle to this point is parallel to the vector
$$\mathbf v\ =\ \begin{pmatrix}a-3 \\ b-4\end{pmatrix}$$
The line $y=2x+3$ is parallel to the vector
$$\mathbf w\ =\ \begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 2\end{pmatrix}$$
(it has gradient $2$). The two vectors are orthogonal, so their dot product is zero:
$$\begin{align*}\mathbf v\cdot\mathbf w\ &=\ 0 \\ \implies\quad(a-3)\cdot1+(b-4)\cdot2\ &=\ 0 \\ \implies\quad a+2b\ &=\ 11\ \ldots\ \fbox1\end{align*}$$
As $(a,b)$ lies on the line $y=2x+3$, i.e. $2x-y=-3$ we have
$$2a-b\ =\ -3\ \ldots\ \fbox2$$
Now solve $\fbox1$ and $\fbox2$ to find the point of tangency; the distance between this point and $(3,4)$ will be the radius of the circle.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Formula for equation of tangent:

$$(y-4)=m(x-3) \pm r\sqrt{1+m^2}$$
correlate it with $$y=2x+3$$

Your $m$ is $2$